# Xamarin Android Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so

Tags: android, xamarin, crash, xamarin.android, native

I released an application and I get these native crashes especially from Galaxy J2(90% of crashes). Users say when App starts it is an immidiate crash. So far I got 25 crashes and I cant even find what is wrong to solve. I am unable to debug on Galaxy J2 but every device that I run the application works with no problem. Here is crash report.

```
Revision: '4'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 4110, tid: 4110, name: sth.someappname  >>> com.sth.someappname <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '* Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/b5fafb24/source/mono/mono/mini/method-to-ir.c:12777, condition `mono_arch_opcode_supported (OP_ATOMIC_STORE_I4)' not met
'
r0 00000000  r1 0000100e  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
r4 b6f14e38  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
r8 b4542cac  r9 00000000  sl b47709b8  fp bef19930
ip 0000100e  sp bef198d8  lr b6d67e79  pc b6d8bb5c  cpsr 600e0010

backtrace:
#00 pc 0003bb5c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00017e75  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
#02 pc 00018a8b  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00015325  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
#04 pc 00012fb0  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00291cdc  /data/app/com.sth.someappname-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which architectures did you enable for the package?

Comment: I enabled all of them. But all crashes are on `ARM`

Comment: I think the problem is here somewhere https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/mini/method-to-ir.c  on the line
g_assert (mono_arch_opcode_supported (OP_ATOMIC_STORE_I4));
where  g_assert() is defined like
#define             g_assert(expr)
Debugging macro to terminate the application if the assertion fails. If the assertion fails (i.e. the expression is not true), an error message is logged and the application is terminated.
The macro can be turned off in final releases of code by defining G_DISABLE_ASSERT when compiling the application.

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.Android` is this compiled with?

Comment: I got rid of this issue by removing thread.sleep() function from splash screen. Then I decided to remove all of them from project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of this issue by removing thread.sleep() function from splash screen. Then I decided to remove all of them from project.